# Will a react component reset its state when it re-renders?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react functional component and declares my state as:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<boolean>(true);
```

When this function re-renders when one of my props changes, does myState get reset to true ?

Comment: how about just try it and check if it is happening or not?

Comment: No, not unless it unmounts/remounts

Comment: This is very helpful for understanding when React resets a component (state gets reset) and when it re-renders (state is maintained):  https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, in React, when our state changes or our props change, the component is re-rendered, but **rendering does not change the state**, if you want to change the state by changing the props, you can use the following code:

For example your component has two props `id, title` when change `id` or `title` you want to set `myState` to `true`. Your component should be:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({id, title}) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(true);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setMyState(true);
  },[id, title])
  
  return (<div id={id}>{title}</div>)

}
```

Comment: what does adding [id, title] do ?

Comment: we can use an array of dependencies as a second argument of the useEffect hook. With it, the callback runs only if some of the elements of the array change.

Comment: thanks. where can i read more about this '2nd argument' as list of dependencies?

Answer (score 15):

Value of state will not get altered automatically after a re-render.

***In react, it is always one-way transition:***

Change of state will trigger the **render()** method.

Render method will not trigger state change.

Comment: OP is talking about hooks. There's no separate render method, whole component is a method.

Comment: His answer is still accurate regardless of whether it's via a hook, is it not?

Comment: Functional components still 'render'. It's just not done via a `render()` method as it's not in a class. The point being made (I think) is that an update to state will cause a re-rendering of the component while a re-rendering of the component does not itself update state.

Comment: `"Value of state will not get altered automatically after a re-render"` - altering value is different from reassigning. What I would like to know is that are the state values reassigned with same value after re-render? This information can be useful when state values are objects because the object reference might change after re-render if React assigns a new object to the state. This can in turn cause the child component to re-render even if the object data didn't change (if the state is being passed as prop to the child component).

Answer (score 2):

**No**, The state will remain as it is until your component unmounts.

If you want to trigger something while unmounting then you can use `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
useEffect(()=>{
//code

return ()=>{
  //unMount Code
}
},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, `useEffect` may be an unnecessary expense as you can just pass a key prop to the child.
`<ChildComponent key={the_prop_you_need_from_parent} />`
When you set this key as the props in question, React will rerender whenever the value of key changes.
See https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#resetting-all-state-when-a-prop-changes

Comment: Neat, didn't know this.